# Python socket strangly hanged - sometimes (client connects with flash) - python 3.2

Tags: python, flash, sockets

I experience strange behavior of sockets in Python (3.2). Client connects to my application using Flash. Most of the time there is nothing unusual but sometimes python crashes in a way that should not have taken place - enter into infinite loops. Below I attach to the loop code and error message in the log. Python hang on `bytesRecived = sock.recv(64)` and receive `b''` witch is visible in log.

code:

```
try:
    buff = ''
    allBytesRecived = []
    timeout = sock.gettimeout()
    sock.settimeout(10.0)
    tries = 0
    while len(buff) < 64 and tries < 64:
        tries += 1
        bytesRecived = sock.recv(64)
        allBytesRecived.append(bytesRecived)
        comm = str(bytesRecived, config.encoding)
        buff += comm

        #flash connection and his strage security policy
        if buff[:24] == config.flash.policy_request:
            cross = open(config.flash.crossdomain,'rb').read()
            cross+=b'\x00' #end string
            sock.send(cross);
            raise FlashCrossdomainException()

    if len(buff) < 64:
        logger.critical('Hanged! buff=%s bytes=%s timeout=%s' % (repr(buff), repr(allBytesRecived), repr(sock.gettimeout())))
        raise InvalidSessionException('Unknown error')
    sock.settimeout(timeout)

except FlashCrossdomainException as e:
    raise e
except socket.timeout:
    raise InvalidSessionException('Timeout on signing in to system')
except socket.error as e:
    logger.exception(e)
    raise InvalidSessionException('Unknown IO error')
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e)
    raise InvalidSessionException('Unknown error')
```

log error:

```
CRITICAL: Hanged! buff='' bytes=[b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''] timeout=10.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python's `socket` module closely matches the BSD socket API.

when the remote side of a socket (here, your flash client) is closed, the `recv()` call on the local side (here, your python server) will return an empty string (`''`). there is no need to continue processing, since the client won't send anything more: the channel is closed.

on the other hand, since your socket is non-blocking, if a socket timeout occurs because the client does not send any data within the specified time limit (10 seconds), then the `recv()` call will raise a `socket.timeout` exception, which you can catch and process accordingly.

you should add a test after the `recv()` call:

```
bytesRecived = sock.recv(64)
if not len(bytesRecived):
    raise InvalidSessionException('connection reset')
```

Comment: Now, I realize that sometimes client can disconnect before I set timeout on socket. I think that's the case. Yours solution will solve the problem. Thanks